# constant values -> iterate through to check against value -> msg

Tags: php, foreach, constants

How could I create a class with constants and multiple values, then iterate through all of them to check if contains certain value of '***300***', and if so prompt message with the const name, ie. '***EYE***' is success.

*Multiple constants with multiple values:*

```
class Specs
{
    const EYE = '300';
    const FRED = '9';
    const TOO_DEMO = 'hfkskakaka';
    const MID_DEMO = 'Lorem Ipsum';
    const VERY_DEMO = 'Blah Blah';
    const DEMO_ZERO = '5';
    const DEMO_INCR = '10';
}
```

*Attempt to iterate through all to check if 300 exists in one, if so, pull name and use in message prompt.*

```
foreach ($Specs == 300) {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how:

```
class Specs
    {
        const EYE = '300';
        const FRED = '9';
        const TOO_DEMO = 'hfkskakaka';
        const MID_DEMO = 'Lorem Ipsum';
        const VERY_DEMO = 'Blah Blah';
        const DEMO_ZERO = '5';
        const DEMO_INCR = '10';

        static function getConstants() {
            $oClass = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
            return $oClass->getConstants();
        }

    } 

    $consts = Specs::getConstants();

    foreach ($consts as $constname => $constvalue) {
        if($constvalue=="300") {
              echo $constname;
        }
        // echo $constname." : ".$constvalue."\n";
    }
```

The example is basically taken from the PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/de/reflectionclass.getconstants.php

Having an associative array you can do every check you want :-)

Comment: Thanks, so all makes sense; however how is it checking for value '300'? I dont see it declared in foreach?

Comment: Edited, should be straightforward though.